# iOS - view controller respond to data change from uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using a color picker (UIView subclass) in my view controller written by someone else, and it contains several subviews that handles touch events. The color picker has a public variable "color", and it's **updated** when user interacts with the subviews.

```
public class SwiftHSVColorPicker: UIView {
    var colorWheel: ColorWheel!
    ...

    public var color: UIColor!
    ...
}
```

See: https://github.com/johankasperi/SwiftHSVColorPicker/blob/master/Source/SwiftHSVColorPicker.swift

I have referenced this color picker view and a label in my view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorPicker: SwiftHSVColorPicker!
@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!
```

How can I update the label text **whenever** the "color" data change from the color picker view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible you need to modify it
there are two ways  ：

1.

```
var colorChanged : ((UIColor!)->())?// add a callback for the colorpicker

func hueAndSaturationSelected(hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat) {
    self.hue = hue
    self.saturation = saturation
    self.color = UIColor(hue: self.hue, saturation: self.saturation, brightness: self.brightness, alpha: 1.0)
    brightnessView.setViewColor(self.color)

    self.colorChanged?(self.color) //call it at this method

    selectedColorView.setViewColor(self.color)
}

colorPicker.colorChanged = {[weak self]  color in

        self?.label.textColor = color //do something with your label

}
```

2.

```
dynamic public var color: UIColor! // add the dynamic keyword
colorPicker.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "color", options:[.Initial, .New], context: nil) // add an observer for the color 


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    //do something with the color
    if let color = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? UIColor {
        self.label.textColor = color
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it works like a charm! I just couldn't find an iOS equivalent to callbacks/listeners in Android...